# generate methods inside classes with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, abstract

I want to generate classes with **JAXB** which extend some abstract class. The extended class is used for rows operations inside a `JTable` so it has methods inside like: `clone`, `clear` etc. Is there a way to also generate these methods (already populated) when generating with **JAXB**?

Thank you in advance for your answers.